# What's wrong with my simple button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm essentially trying to create a div which is an image of a button, and when the user clicks it a function is executed. For some reason the div is not showing up at all! What in the world am I setting wrong?

CSS:

```
#customizeButton
{
  background-image:url('images/customizeButton.png');
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  left:25%;
  width:370px;
  height:350px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size:100% auto;
  z-index: 150;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="customizeButton"></div>
```

It has to be something with the CSS side. I've got almost identical code for another "button" which I use as an exit button, but it uses a text character instead of an image. It works just fine...

Here's the code for reference:

CSS:

```
#statSheetExitButton
{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 17%;
  left: 74%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="statSheetExitButton">X</div>
```

---

And again, the question is why the `customizeButton` is not showing up.

**EDIT: ANSWER** The problem was that I had the html code for my initial Stat Sheet components in another html file in the same folder, and my program was only listening to that file.

Comment: Is the url to the image correct? If for example your stylesheet is in `root/css` and your image in `root/images` you wil have to add `../` before the url.

Comment: That should not be the issue as in the same CSS file I have `.StatsContainer
{
 background-image:url('images/playerStats.png');
}`    And it show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the correct path to your image?

`background-image:url('customizeButton.png');`

This would only work if the `img` was in the same directory as the css.

Comment: Forgot to edit the sample code above, which I just fixed. I did have images/customizeButton.png, as my images are in a different folder, but it still does not show

Comment: Try `../images/customizeButton.png` or even use the full site path `http://www.yoursite.com/images/customizeButton.png`

Comment: I tried the ../images and no change. I then did the full path and still no show. :/ I'm just completely stumped!

Comment: Place a border rule in there and see if the `div` even shows... `border:1px solid red;`

Comment: Removed the image aspect and replaced it with the same code as my exit button, except slightly moving where the text would show up as to avoid overlapping. And... no text. Must be something with the div not wanting to show because of other factors

Comment: The border idea is a good one, I tested in on my exitButton and the border appeared, but still nothing with my customizeButton.

Comment: Also, you might try removing all the styles rules and then adding them back one at a time.  See if any choke.  Use the border one again for this.

Comment: I found that the problem was that I had the html code in another file in the same folder that my program was listening to rather than the html code in my StatSheet.html. Since you took the most effort to help me with my problem, and I did find the border suggestion useful, I'm selecting your answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are absolute positioning your element. Could you be positioning it on top of a relative positioned element that is causing it to be placed outside of the viewport of the browser screen. **Use the inspector tools in Chrome, Firefox or Safari to find out where the div is**. That'll get you on the right track.

Comment: All of the positioning in the CSS file are absolute

Answer (score 0):

I think your div is empty so that,s why div is not showing, try to write some text or some thing else in div

Comment: You don't have to, provided that width and height are specified correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

- display: block; missing
- you don't need background-repeat(nor -webkit-background-size), because you are giving it a height & width
- if you are only positioning this container, you do not need z-index

Comment: For the z-index, there is another div I'm placing this button on top of

Comment: No need for `display: block` in div element. Unless it isn't globally set to inline, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button is inside a positioned element, which isn't itself hidden.